# Подписка на интересные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, уведомления, rss, подписки

Предположим, я увидел интересный вопрос (заданный естественно не мною), и я не знаю, как его решить.

Есть какие-то варианты уведомлений для пользователя, о том, что у вопроса, который интересен, появился ответ, решающий проблему? Иными словами, подписка на решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь можно [следить за интересующими вас сообщениями](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/260198).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10):

Можно подписаться на RSS-ленту вопроса. К примеру, возьмём ваш вопрос: [Регулярные выражения. получить строку между тегами, но не сами теги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1063504/15479).

Там справа есть кнопка [Лента вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/1063504).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете к себе в читалку добавить эту ленту. Тогда будете получать обновления о новых ответах.

Answer (score 9):

RSS - замечательный и, скорее всего, предпочтительный вариант (как предложил @Suvitruf).

Для отдельных вопросов, я использую добавление в избранное – звездочка около интересного вопроса. Мой сценарий использования следующий:

- мне не слишком важно узнать об обновлении вопроса сразу как это случилось. Мне хватит и "когда-нибудь".
- Раз в месяцок - я захаживаю на страницу [избранных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/337980/anton-menshov?tab=favorites) (ну конкретно эта у меня пустая, а вот на [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/20688/anton-menshov?tab=favorites) используется). Если по какому-то из вопросов в моем избранном была активность – он выделится желтым. Также есть сортировки по активности и т.д.

Это не совсем то, что вы просили – ибо уведомлений нет, и вам нужно быть проактивным. Однако, конкретно мне при моих запросов это удобнее чем RSS. RSS я использую сугубо при подписке на тэги (это уж дело вкуса).